# Is there a R function that makes y-axis percentage variable dependent instead of total observation dependent

Tags: r, class, ggplot2, bar-chart

First post here, so please tell me if im doing something wrong!

I'm just starting out learning "r" and am currently partaking in a "titanic kaggle assignment" for one of the correlations im using barplots to show ( this person survived due to... )

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data=train, aes(x=Pclass, fill=Survived)) + 
        ggtitle("Class distribution of passengers")+
        scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)+
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+ #center title
        labs(y= "Count", x = "Class")+ #naming X and Y axis
        geom_bar(position = "stack") # bars in plot arent stacked but side by side
```

[image]

^ is the code i am using where i make the Y-axis percentage based instead of a total numeric value.

I noted that the % value is based out of total data observations, and wonder if i can make the Y axis in essence 100% for each bar, and their % distribution only dependent on the class ( 1 , 2 , 3 ).

so in essense it would become something like this ( pardon my artistic skills ):

[image]

Thanks in advance for the help! if you got any forum posting tips please do tell me aswell to make it a bit more readable in the future.

Comment: try `geom_bar(position = 'fill', stat = 'identity')`?

Comment: @heds1 I've attempted this with both copy,pasting it or using my own "stat" value since i didnt really know what "identity" means so i assumed its my "Pclass" . In both cases i get a error in essense: ```{r} ggplot(data=train, aes(x=Pclass, fill=Survived)) + 
        ggtitle("Class distribution of passengers")+
        scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(accuracy = 100))+
        theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+ #center title
        labs(y= "Count", x = "Class")+ #naming X and Y axis
        geom_bar(position = 'fill', stat = 'identity') ```

Comment: FYI your first question was clear and well written. Just read the documentation a bit more closely next time! `?geom_bar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help page of `geom_bar` says:

> By default, multiple bars occupying the same x position will be stacked atop one another by position_stack(). If you want them to be dodged side-to-side, use position_dodge() or position_dodge2(). Finally, position_fill() shows relative proportions at each x by stacking the bars and then standardising each bar to have the same height.

In other words, you need to use:

`geom_bar(position = position_fill())` or equivalently `geom_bar(position = "fill")`

The advantage of using `position_fill()` rather than `"fill"` is that you can pass arguments if you need to tweak the position (which is quite uncommon). See `?position_fill`.

Comment: I see now, true i keep forgetting that ?function is a thing and usually tend to instant reach to see on google if someone had a similar issue. Thanks for the help! this worked, and now i also know why it works.